# Handling exception - socket connection error and return to previous activity (another thread in another class)

Tags: android, sockets, android-intent

I want to handle the exception of a connection (eg. client has provided incorrect IP address of the server or the server is not listening).

As a result, I want back to previous activity in which in EditText client can change the IP address and then pass it to the next activity using Intent.

```
public class TcpClient extends Activity  {

public static String aHost;
public String aSocketIn;
public static int aSocketInInt;
public Handler uiHandler;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bundle_result);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

        aHost = intent.getStringExtra("addressIp");
        aSocketIn = intent.getStringExtra("socketIn");

    aSocketInInt = Integer.parseInt(aSocketIn);

    uiHandler = new Handler();

    ClientInThread clientInThread = new ClientInThread(aHost,aSocketInInt,uiHandler,imageView);
    (new Thread(clientInThread)).start();
} }

class ClientInThread extends Thread implements Runnable {

public Bitmap bitmap = null;
public Handler handler;
String Host;
int SocketIn;
ImageView imageView;
ClientIn clientIn;
Socket socket;

ClientInThread(String Host, int SocketIn, Handler handler, ImageView imageView) {
    this.Host = Host;
    this.SocketIn = SocketIn;
    this.handler = handler;
    this.imageView = imageView;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        InetAddress serwerAddress = InetAddress.getByName(Host);
        socket = new Socket(serwerAddress, SocketIn);
        clientIn = new ClientIn(socket);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // The following solution has not worked. Error in Intent and startActivity()
                Intent intent = Intent(TcpClient.this, MyConnection.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // finish();
            }
        });
    }

        while(socket.isConnected()) {
            bitmap = clientIn.Receive();
            if (bitmap == null) {
                // Downloading error
                return;
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });
        }
} }
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace! Its much harder to find out what is wrong without a stack trace...

Comment: TCP connection is working properly and the application works correctly. I want to handle only exception when the client in the previous activity enters an incorrect IP address of the server.

MyConnection -> TcpClient (if the IP address is correct client connects to the server, otherwise it throws an exception, which I want to handle - back to previous activity (MyConnection).

Comment: If you want it to happen on catching an exception you should put the intent inside the catch brace. Why would you need a thread to start an activity? And try using getApplicationContext() instead of TcpClient.this

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be to send a message to the UI Thread (TcpClient) that I want to call Intent and startActivity ?  But I would have to also interrupt thread?